# Adding custom content-types to Firefox application handler?

Tags: json, firefox, content-type

In Firefox, whenever I request a page that returns a Content-type of "application/json", Firefox saves the file into /tmp but then says "/tmp/json.php could not be opened, because the associated helper application does not exist. Change the association in your preferences."  Well, I go into Edit > Preferences > Applications, and there's no content type listed there that seems to have anything to do with application/json.

Is it possible to add an entry for this type?  (Or for a random custom type I make up, like "foo/bar"?)  I see a file called mimeTypes.rdf which looks promising.

Comment: [Firefox has a native viewer now](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/JSON_viewer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it is the mimeTypes.rdf file which controls these things, so I'll just edit it by hand.  (Or go find an add-on.)

Answer (score 4):

For those looking in 2021, the file is now called `handlers.json`.

See:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-firefox-behavior-when-open-file

Answer (score 0):

For users of the future: [JSONView](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10869) is a very nice add-on for reading JSON :)